# Why is this C# load form not working?

Tags: c#, winforms, config

I am trying to get a value from a config file when the form loads it puts it in a Textbox. I am using Program.cs to get the value from the config file. Everything looks setup correctly but when I run the form no value is there.

```
public form()
{   
    InitializeComponent();

    string NewValue = Program.Value;
    Textbox.Text = NewValue;
}
```

Program.cs:

```
public static string Value = "";         

switch (element.ChildNodes[i].Name)
{
    case "FileInfo":
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < childNodeList.Count; j++)
        {
            switch (childNodeList[j].Name)
            {
                case "Value":
                {
                    Program.Value = childNodeList[j].InnerText;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

         .........

    }

     ---------

}
```

Config:

```
<config>
  <FileInfo>
  <Value>1234</Value>
  </FileInfo>
</config>
```

Comment: how does Program.Value work - it sounds like that is where the problem is.

Comment: How does `Program` look like? How does it get the value from the config file? That's most likely where your problem is.

Comment: Could you show us the code for Program.Value?

Comment: Have you single-stepped the code to make sure you're reading the config file correctly? Is the line that sets the value ever being executed?

Comment: Have you setup breakpoints and verified that it's executing in the right order?

Comment: Have you tried to set `public static string Value = "somevalue";` to see if the problem is that there is no value at the end of the `for`?

Comment: Updated question - and still left out the most crucial part

Comment: Where do you call the code you listed from Program.cs? What method is it in?

Comment: I thought Program.Value will call that method?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are using at least .net 2.0

- Add reference to System.Configuration to your project
- Make sure that your app.config looks properly:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
      <appSettings>
          <add key="myKey" value="myValue"/>
      </appSettings>
  </configuration>
  ```
- Change you code to use `ConfigurationManager` to retrieve the value:

  ```
  using System.Configuration;
  using System.Windows.Forms;

  namespace SO6065319
  {
          public partial class Form1 : Form
          {
                  public Form1()
                  {
                          InitializeComponent();
                          textBox1.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"];
                  }
          }
  }
  ```

Here textBox1 is the name of the text box on the form.
You can see now "myValue" in your textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx).